# In java, how would I add a string to a string variable?

Tags: java, string, random, int

I have code that generates a random number form 0-1 3 times and I need it to be added to a variable so it turns into a binary number.So, in theory, this would run three times and possibly give me 101;

```
String storage = null;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 3) {
            int binny = this.giveMeBinary();
            storage.concat(String.valueOf(binny));
            i++;
        }

        int ans = Integer.parseInt(storage);
```

But when I try and run this I get the NullPointerException error for storage. Is there a way to just "add" a string to the variable?

the method *giveMeBinary* just returns a 0 or a 1.

Comment: also note that `storage.concat(...)` will not change the value of storage. You need to do `storage = storage.concat(...)`.

Comment: As an aside, if your goal is `ans` and not `storage`, you can do this easily with bit arithmetic: `while(i<3) {ans <<= 1; ans |= this.giveMeBinary();i++;}` or `whle(i<3) { ans |= this.giveMeBinary()<<i;i++;}`

Comment: ahhhhh yes....I see what you mean...it doesn't store the new value into storage.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is that you are initializing the string to null. Doing something like so should solve your problem:

```
        String storage = "";
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 3) {
            int binny = this.giveMeBinary();
            storage += (String.valueOf(binny));
            i++;
        }

        int ans = Integer.parseInt(storage);
```

However, concatenating strings in such a manner is not recommended. What you can do is use a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) like so:

```
        StringBuilder storage = new StringBuilder();
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 3) {
            int binny = this.giveMeBinary();
            storage.append(String.valueOf(binny));
            i++;
        }

        int ans = Integer.parseInt(storage.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You get the NullPointerException because you set the variable storage to null. You should start with

```
String storage = "";
```

Comment: ... and then get an exception in `Integer.parseInt` because `storage` still refers to an empty string after the loop?

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems:

- You're never assigning a non-null value to `storage`, but you're calling the `concat` method on it. That will always throw a `NullPointerException`
- You're  assuming `String.concat` will modify the existing string value. It doesn't. Strings are immutable in Java.

I would suggest using a `StringBuilder` instead, and calling `append` in the loop:

```
int i = 0;
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
while (i < 3) {
    int binny = this.giveMeBinary();
    builder.append(binny);
    i++;
}
int ans = Integer.parseInt(builder.toString());
```

Quite why you're then parsing a *binary* number such as "011" as if it were a *decimal* number is a different matter. What do you actually want the result to be? Do you really want the numbers 0, 1, 10, 11, 100, 101, 110 or 111?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use String concatenation then just initialise storage to "" (empty string) then use

```
storage += String.valueOf(binny);
```

but if you are looping and building Strings you should really use StringBuilder since Strings are immutable

```
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
```

then

```
buffer.append(binny);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a binary number, i.e. a random number between 0 and 7 or 000 and 111 in binary.

```
int ans = giveMeBinary() * 4 + giveMeBinary() * 2 + giveMeBinary();
```

however if you want a decimal number which looks like a binary number.

```
int ans = giveMeBinary() * 100 + giveMeBinary() * 10 + giveMeBinary();
```

Answer (score 0):

After you correct `NullPointerException`, try this:

```
storage = storage + String.valueOf(binny)
```

...and then read about [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
String storage = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

It throws a NullPointerException because storage is null. Try the following

```
StringBuilder storage = new StringBuilder();
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 3) {
            int binny = this.giveMeBinary();
            storage.append(String.valueOf(binny));
            i++;
        }

        int ans = Integer.parseInt(storage.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

variable storage is not initialized..Following code will throw NPE

```
storage.concat(....)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get a NullPointerException is that the "storage" variable is never initialized. So the first call to "storage.concat" will try to perform an operation on a NullPointer.

For doing string concatenation you'll want to use a mutable class like StringBuilder, the String class is immutable (you cannot modify an instance of it).

Here's an example using StringBuilder:

```
StringBuilder storage = new StringBuilder();
int i = 0;
while (i < 3) {
   int binny = this.giveMeBinary();
   storage.append(binny);
   i++;
}

int ans = Integer.parseInt(storage.toString());
```